# Cold war submarine game for the ST

Tags: identify-this-game, atari-st

I'm trying to recall the name of a game I spent too much time playing on my ST. It was a simulation of cold war sub combat. It took place entirely on a map view, where you controlled NATO subs, including British and US I'm not sure if others as well. There was no "internal view" or anything like that, you pointed and clicked on the map to perform operations at a fleet level.

One key bit of gameplay I recall was when your US subs had SUBROCs on them and you'd launch and then wait for them to drop into the water right over the enemy while you sent your subs in the opposite direction.

It was not Red Storm Rising, 688 or any of the other "common" ones. Nor was it Harpoon, although it felt more like that that any of the others I can find.

Comment: I had a quick check to refresh my memory, and it's also not Hunt for Red October. I suspect you already knew this.

Comment: "SUBROC" was an arcade title around that time.

Comment: Maybe better off asking this on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: oh no, such questions are off topic there...

Comment: /r/tipofmyjoystick on reddit might prove a good source of answers too... intrigued to know what this is!

Comment: @MattLacey There's also a channel dedicated to asking those sorts of "What am I remembering?" questions on the MobyGames Discord.

Comment: You sure it wasn't Silent Service?

Comment: Silent Service is a WWII game of US subs in the pacific and takes place inside the submarine. It is not a Cold War game with British subs in the North Atlantic that takes place solely on a map. So, yes, I'm sure its not Silent Service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this might be "Under the Ice":

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bmd-edm9pjw

Comment: Oh, yes, I should have updated this! I contacted the author and wrote a wiki article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Ice